# JSF invoke backing bean method and reRender components on ENTER key

Tags: javascript, events, jsf, richfaces

I have a datatable with  as search fields. I want a method on the backing bean to be invoked when ENTER key is pressed, as well as the DataTable to be re-rendered.

My approach so far only works in IE 6, and 7, not in FF. This is the inputText:

```
<h:inputText
 value="#{applicantProductListBean.applicantNameFilterValue}"
 id="applicantNameFilterValue" onkeypress="submitByEnter(event)">
</h:inputText>
```

and this is the Javascript method I am invoking:

```
 function submitByEnter(e){
 if(e.keyCode==13){
      // alert("Enter was pressed");
      e.returnValue=false;
      e.cancel=true;
      document.getElementById("applicantProductListForm:refreshButton").click();
 } 
}
```

As you can see, the Javascript method clicks on the button refresh, which exists on the page:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Refresh" id="refreshButton"
 action="#{applicantProductListBean.refreshData}"
 image="/images/icons/refresh48x48.gif"
 reRender="table, scroller">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

The refreshData method does not return anything. As said before, this only works in IE 6 and IE 7.

Does anyone know why it does not work in FF?

An alternative I was considering was HotKey, which can indeed catch the event of ENTER, **but** it can only invoke Javascript, so it isn't appropriate.

Is the proper way to do this via RichFaces or plain JSF?

Cheers!

**UPDATE:**

Slightly modified the answer by BalusC, the script that works is:

```
if (event.preventDefault) {
// Firefox
event.preventDefault(); 
} else {
// IE 
event.returnValue = false; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the JS block by:

```
function submitByEnter(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("applicantProductListForm:refreshButton").click();
    } 
}
```

or better,

```
function submitByEnter(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("applicantProductListForm:refreshButton").click();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the input's `onkeypress` by

```
onkeypress="return submitByEnter(event)"
```

If that doesn't work, run the JS debugger of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to see if JS code behaves as expected.

Comment: You're welcome. It will however not work on (very) old browsers. Test it in all browsers you're supposed to support.

Comment: I made an update (I check if preventDefault exists and either call it or set returnValue  to false). I tested it in IE6, IE7, FF.

Answer (score 0):

Following did work for me:

```
<h:panelGrid onkeypress="searchByEnterAndReturn(event)">
    <b:aCustomComponent value="#{evolutionBackingAction.value}" id="someID"/>
</h:panelGrid>

<a4j:commandButton value="Search Now" action="search" id="searchButton"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function searchByEnterAndReturn(e){ 
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            document.getElementById("generalForm:pageHeader:searchButton").click(); 
        }  
     }
</script>
```

This works, but to find the ID of my search button I had to search through the source code of my page as the searchButton id itself couldn't be found!

I could have done this on the customComponent but I'm having control over the source code of this component and the onkeypress method is not implemented.