# Update a component of parent jsf page

Tags: jsf-2

I have a main jsf page, it contains a link to a popup window.

I want to update a component of the main jsf page. when i close the popup window.

popup.xhtml:

```
 <h:commandButton value="close" onclick="return window.close();"   
                  action="showDevoir.xhtml"> 
      <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":devoirForm"  />
 </h:commandButton>
```

main.xhtml

```
<form id="devoirForm" >

 <p:panel id="devoir" />

</form>
```

When i close the popup, i want to update the panel component of the form with id="devoirForm"

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using PrimeFaces.

Just use `<p:dialog>` instead of `window.open()`. See also the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogForm.jsf). This creates a `<div>` element in the very same window, so you would just have instant access to the main form from there.

Comment: Why the render attribute of Ajax can not do the job?

Comment: Just because it's not in the same page.

Comment: Thank you for your resposes guy. Good idea for the <p:dialog>

Answer (score 0):

Add to your main page a JavaScript function that updates said component. Call it from the onunload event from your popup windows.

I am less familiar with the issue of rerendering a component JavaScript; in the worst of the worlds you can add a commandButton that refreshes the component, make it invisible through CSS, and make the JS launch its `click` event ([like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317714/jsf-invoke-backing-bean-method-and-rerender-components-on-enter-key))